# My EVO 3D is narcissistic and won't stop taking pictures of itself

Tags: htc-evo, stock-android, screenshots

My SD card is filling up with screen caps. I mean, it's not a big problem that's taxing my storage. Still, [with all the activity in my pockets](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14206/80), my phone frequently like to waste time photographing itself like some webcam girl.

I am running a stock EVO 3D from HTC; no roots, no screen cap apps or anything. I am thrilled that there might be native screen-capping. However, when I have googled to find out how to do it, there are either non-native instructions (it's native), or there are instructions to just shake the crap out of it (which I have tried, and does not cap screens). I admit it is totally possible there is some key-combo I have not found yet; but if there is one, I need to disable/remap it.

My question is two fold;

- So assuming the problem is between the keyboard and chair, and assuming that the behavior leading to the screen caps isn't going to change (i.e. me putting my phone in my pocket); How can I get the phone to stop screen capping at random times?
- As mentioned in the comment below, hitting [LOCK+Home] will take screen caps with my HTC EVO 3D; can these buttons or this behavior be remapped?

Comment: On the one hand +1 for the great title, on the other hand, how to take screencaps on the Evo 3D is in this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1759/how-to-take-a-screenshot-with-an-android-phone/14166#14166 Is there anything about the way you hold/pocket it, or a case you use that makes those buttons particularly vulnerable?

Comment: (A) Glad to finally know the combination, thanks! (B) Is there a way to remap or disable the screen-capping? I am not using a case, and typically have headphones in with the base in the bottom of the pocket, the lock key not up against anything.

Comment: There is a bug on the sensation in which the lock bottom doesn't do its job and when you hit home a screenshot is taken. It could be that the Evo 3D has the same problem... no solution AFAIK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this app: [ButtonRemapper (XDA Thread)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464)

It takes a little reading to figure out how to properly configure this to your needs but once it's done it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks much, unfortunately my phone is not rooted; are there any remapping apps that do not require root?

Comment: I don't think so because of security reasons. If I see something I'll get back to you!